# Semantic ui checkbox strange bahaviour

Tags: jquery, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying ti use Semantic Ui checkbox, but it behaves strange. You have to click somewhere out of checkbox, to make it's background change color regardless of state

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/6393n6e9/][1]
```

it works ok on Semantic Ui website in same browser

```
[http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#/definition][2]
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have not included the semantic package to the fiddle, but on your dev environment, you have to initialize the checkbox like this:

```
// this will affect all elements that have the classes ui & checkbox
$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
```

or

```
// this will only affect the one you need, if it has any id specified
$('#myCheckbox').checkbox();
```

Also make sure that semantic-ui files are properly loaded, and look for typos (this got me last time, lol)